# What causes the "Incompatible operand types" error?

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors, operators, type-conversion

I am trying to implement iSortableStack Interface via a class.

Here's my main function,

```
public class SampleStack<E> {
    E ch;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ISortableStack<Character> s = new SortableStack<Character>();
        SampleStack demo = new SampleStack();
        while ((demo.ch == System.in.read()) != '\n')
            if (!s.isFull())
                s.push((Character) demo.ch);
        while (!s.isEmpty())
            System.out.print(s.pop());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

But I am getting one error, on this line,

```
while ((demo.ch == System.in.read()) != '\n')
```

**Error : Incompatible operand types Object and int**

What is wrong here ?

Comment: and if you declare demo as `SampleStack<Character>`?

Comment: Rather than suppressing warnings (as you have done with the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`), you should heed the compiler's advice. If you don't understand that advice, then you should read-up until you do (which is what you're doing by asking here, an excellent choice.) In general: *don't ignore warnings unless you know what they mean.*

Comment: What exactly is a sortable stack, other than a contradiction in terms?

Answer (score 4):

There are two severe problems here that have nothing to do with generics.

First, `demo.ch == System.in.read()` is a `boolean` expression. The result of `read()` (an `int`) will be auto-boxed to an `Integer`, and the identity of that object will be tested against `demo.ch` (which is `null`).

I think that what you want here is the assignment operator, `=`. This will assign the `read()` result to `demo.ch`.

The next problem is that it looks like you expect `demo.ch` to be a `Character` (based on the casts you are using). However, you are trying to assign an `int` (the result of `read()`) to it. Primitive types can be "auto-boxed" when necessary, that is, they can be converted to a wrapper object like `Character` or `Integer`, but only when the value to be converted is a constant expression that can be represented by the target type. Here, the value is variable, so the conversion cannot be performed implicitly.

You could work around this by explicitly casting the `read()` result to a `char`, and then letting the auto-boxing convert it to a `Character`, but that would hide EOF, which is represented by a value of -1. I recommend using something like this instead:

```
while (true) {
  int ch = System.in.read();
  if ((ch < 0) || (ch == '\n'))
    break;
  if (!s.isFull())
    s.push((char) ch);
 }
```

Note that we don't use `demo` here at all, so the problems with its type parameter are irrelevant.

Comment: Note that `Character c; c = (int) 3;` is indeed defined and works perfectly well. The rest of what you say is sound however, especially about the hazards of autoboxing the result of read() to a `Character`.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill: That is interesting, I didn't realize that, and I still don't fully understand what is happening there. It appears that that assignment only works if it the `int` rvalue can be statically determined to fit in a `char` without narrowing. For example, `c = (int) -1` and `c = (int) 65536` do not work. Also, the analysis is local; `int i = 3; c = i;` does not work in this case. Do you know where this is covered in the JLS?

Comment: I think this is covered in the discussion of section 5.2, *Assignment conversion*: "A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, *and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.*"

Comment: @Ernest: That definitely covers it! Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

`SampleStack.ch` is of type `E`. `E` is an object specified by your type parameters. Since you did not specify a type parameter, the compiler puts `Object` in for you. If you wanted `ch` to be a `Character`, you would want `SampleStack<Character> demo = new SampleStack<Character>();` or in Java 7 `SampleStack<Character> demo = new SampleStack<>();`.

Answer (score 1):

You have `==` (equality test) when you want `=` (assignment). You're never actually assigning to `demo.ch`. The equality test returns boolean, rather than char, hence the error message.

You will also need to cast the result from `System.in.read()` to a character from an integer (or else use `SampleStack<Integer>`, or something like that.)

Comment: well casting is an option but there are better options such as the Scanner class.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided a type parameter when you instantiate `SampleStack`, so `demo.ch` is of type `Object`. That obviously can't be compared (or assigned, which is what I suspect you actually wanted to do, anyway) from the `int` coming from `System.in`.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in this code:

- as people pointed out you're making a generic class but you're not generalizing it and using it raw, you need:

  `SampleStack<Character>`
- even if you change it it wont run as you have == instead of =
- even if you change the above two it wont work as System.in.read() returns an int, not a character, You'd need to either make a stack of Integers OR read the value from the input to a variable and then cast it but its not a good practice. I'd use a Scanner or somethign similar to read what the user inputs like this:

  `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   char c = sc.nextChar();`